# Loading json data into forms

Tags: html, angularjs

So I'm creating an AngularJS front end for an application. There are several forms that require  dropdown lists.

What would be the best way to populate these lists, should I create a class for each  with a name and value, or would it be best to create just one class that represents all of the  lists on the form?

Or is there a much easier other way that I should know about?

I have about 20 lists that I'll need to generate, currently I'm supplying JSON with web API controllers similar to the one below.

Thanks for the help!

```
// GET: api/Menu/5
    public ListItems[] Get(string typeOf)
    {
        if(typeOf=="category")
        {
            var listitems = (from a in db.assets
                select new ListItems
                {
                    name = a.name,
                    id = a.id.ToString()

                }).ToArray();

            return listitems;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's depend in your application size. How much lists you have? Are The saved in the javascript (hardcode) or dynamic from the database?

Comment: @MoshFeu edited origional post

Comment: Anyway I recommend to create service like `listManagerSrv` that will take care about get those list from the server and "answer" to the controllers requests. Just one more question. Are all lists "live" together? I mean, have you one page that present all those list? If so, it's better to make a call to the server once, get all those lists. If no, call the server once the client need it. Just keep it in your mind that this is a quick and generic answer.